# How to insert PHP array values using an stored procedure SQL SERVER 2008 R2(mssql)

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this array

```
$REV = Array
(
    0 => 240,
    1 => 241,
    2 => 242,
    3 => 243,
    4 => 249
);
```

and i'm using this code bellow to insert for now, stored each array's element in a row with $id, $userID, Type and Date

```
if (!empty($REV)) {
    foreach ($REV as $val_rev) {
        $values_rev[] = "('" . $ID . "','REV','" . $val_rev . "','" . $IDUSER . "',GETDATE())";
    }
    $values_rev_insert = implode(',', $values_rev);

    $query_rev = "insert into dbo.CCLine (ID,CCType,CSID,IdUSer,DateCreated)values" . $values_rev_insert;
    mssql_query($query_rev);
}
```

But what i want is can use this stored procedure but i dont have idea how to make to insert in one time using the sp:

```
$stmt = mssql_init('sp_insertRev');
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ID', $ID, SQLINT4);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@CCType', 'REV', SQLVARCHAR);
```

The array does not work here

```
mssql_bind($stmt, '@CSID', $val_rev, SQLINT4);//An example
```

---

```
mssql_bind($stmt, '@IdUSer', $IDUSER, SQLCHAR);
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
```

How can i use this SP with the array

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_HCCInsert]
            @ID int
           ,@CCType varchar(10)
           ,@CSID varchar(10)
           ,@IdUSer char(15)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CCID as INT

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[CCLine]
           ([ID]
           ,[CCType]
           ,[CSID]
           ,[IdUSer]
           ,[DateCreated])
     VALUES
           (@ID
           ,@CCType
           ,@CSID
           ,@IdUSer
           ,GETDATE())


      SET @CCID = @@IDENTITY

      Select @CCID as CCID


END
```

Comment: Before thinking about how to store a comma separated list of values into a single column you should think about normalizing your data. A cell in a RDBMS usually represents an atomic value, not a set of values.

Comment: hello @ZombieHunter, the database is normalized, above i´m inserting 4 columns for each element of array, the database is out of my hand, i cant change...what i want is take advantage of the sp, in this case the array only has 5 elements, but in normally production enviroment it can have 3 or 4 hundred elements..thanks for any sugestion or advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found solution to your problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069311/passing-an-array-of-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure)

It's all about passing the array as XML string which is passed to the procedure and in procedure it is used in INSERT SELECT statement with OPENXML function.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_HCCInsert]
(
   @XMLDoc XML
)
```

Then use function `OPENXML` in MSSQL. You should read this topic.
So pseudo code will look like

`INSERT ... SELECT OPENXML(@XML...)`

After you read it and fit to your needs just pass XML to procedure.

Some useful links about OPENXML

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms175160.aspx
- [Using OPENXML in SQL Server 2008 stored proc - INSERT order differs from XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997520/using-openxml-in-sql-server-2008-stored-proc-insert-order-differs-from-xml-doc)
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26499

Moreover, I'd suggest using PDO because it has better abstract layer. I hope that it helped you.

Comment: Hi robert, Do you have good experience with PDO MSSQL in PHP, I'm reading in the manual but it is still in EXPERIMENTAL time?

Comment: what's your problem? :) It's easy because of abstraction layer of PDO. You don't need to worry about in-mechanics of msssql.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use PDO instead of the mssql_* functions, you can still use dblib and you can bind that array quite simply. One thing though, you have 5 elements in that array but only 4 input variables to your stored procedure. This example will assume you only have 4 elements in your array.

```
$sql = "EXEC sp_HCCInsert ?, ?, ?, ?"; // SQL string with ? where params should go
$pdh = new PDO("dblib:host=somthing.somewhere\\INSTANCENAME;port=1433;dbname=MyDatabase;","username","password");
$sth = $pdh->prepare($sql); // Prepare query
$sth->execute($REV); // Execute and bind non-associative array
```

The only caution with using the PDO with dblib on PHP 5.3 or before, it goes and does a prefetch on execute. So if you execute a huge query and you want to loop through each record one at a time... sorry, you get the whole thing buffered first.

Also, you can use an associative array if you'd like

```
$REV = array(":ID" => 240, ":CCType" => 241, ":CSID" => 242, ":IdUSer" => 243);
$sql = "EXEC sp_HCCInsert :ID, :CCType, :CSID, :IdUSer"; // SQL string with named params
$pdh = new PDO("dblib:host=somthing.somewhere\\INSTANCENAME;port=1433;dbname=MyDatabase;","username","password");
$sth = $pdh->prepare($sql); // Prepare query
$sth->execute($REV); // Execute and bind associative array
```

The best part is, the execute method for the PDO::Statement escapes strings! Safety first you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO table column(c1,c2) 
         VALUES('d1','d2'),('dd1','dd2'),('ddd1','ddd2')";// this is the basic sql command

$data = array('data1','data2','data3');
$data = '('.implode(', ',$data).')';
$sql  = "INSERT INTO table column(c1,c2) VALUES $data";

$data = array(array('1','2','3'),array('4','5','6'),array('7','8','9'));
$xa = array();
$a = 0;
foreach($data as $dt)
{
    $xa[$a] =   '('.implode(',',$dt).')';
    ++$a;
}
$data = '('.implode(',',$xa).')';
$sql  = "INSERT INTO table column(c1,c2) VALUES $data";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...but this dont answer my question, something like that is what i have, what i want is insert the array using the stored procedure, read the code below of array at beginning of the question