# Inserting array values in mysql using stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, stored-procedures

I have a table in which i want to insert multiple rows having values from a php array , now i can't figure out how to pass an array in stored procedure .

Example-:   i have a php array having names `['sqlite','mysql','sql']`

now what i want is to send this array to stored procedure and loop through the array taking one value at a time and inserting into the database table.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a string with your list and use a prepared statements to run a query, e.g. -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetFruits(IN fruitArray VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Fruits WHERE Name IN (', fruitArray, ')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

How to use:

SET @fruitArray = '\'apple\',\'banana\'';
CALL GetFruits(@fruitArray);

Comment: Refer to this link this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330557/how-to-insert-php-array-values-using-an-stored-procedure-sql-server-2008-r2mssq

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *

FROM fruits

WHERE FIND_IN_SET ( name, fruit_array );
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:

> Use foreach loop:

```
foreach(condition)
{
  //Create insert query string
}

//insert query
//Execute Query
```

For more help paste code

Comment: @leandronn I have just suggested another solution to insert multiple values in a single query. Please check edited answer.