# How Read data from XML variable in Sqlserver and show in table format?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have below format of xml.

[image]

need to show this data below table format.

[image: Table Format]

Comment: Have you tried some query?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms175160.aspx , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997520/using-openxml-in-sql-server-2008-stored-proc-insert-order-differs-from-xml-doc, http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26499

Comment: I have changes in the XML now it's validate properly, sorry in emergency I have added wrong XML.

Comment: Good qestiong, exactly what I've needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you've made your XML valid, use `nodes`

```
select 
    t.x.value('FacilityID[1]','int') as FacilityID,
    t.x.value('Category[1]','int') as CategryID
from @yourxml.nodes('/Facilities/Facility') t(x)
```